# Checkboxlist multiple value select and display in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, checkboxlist

I am  using C# for a web app will checkboxlist. I write my code below. When I select multiple value from the checkboxlist, it reports error. But for only one value select, It works fine.

The code has two parts:
1. select from checkboxlist (multichoice): the value is the same as in database, where store the related data.
2. display value to gridview: after selecting, show the whole table to gridview to display.

My error is when choose 2 and more value from checkbox, then error says "The variable name `@textInput` has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Can anybody help me solve this problem? or you have any other way to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TestGridview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private int count = 0;
private DataSet dc = new DataSet();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Create the list to store.
    List<String> YrStrList = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            YrStrList.Add(item.Value);
        }
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    // Create the command object
    string str = "SELECT * FROM XML WHERE [Part_Numbber] = @textInput";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    for (int d = 0; d < YrStrList.Count; d++)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string text;
        text = YrStrList[d];
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("textInput", text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "XML");
        if (count == 0) {

            dc = ds.Clone();
            count++;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() != "NULL")
                dc.Tables[0].ImportRow(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]);
        }
    }


    GridView1.DataSource = dc;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

}

Comment: Please attach error that you are getting. For easy select use Linq: 


IEnumerable<string> CheckedItems = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                   .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                   .Select(i => i.Value);

 
Don't forget to add System.Linq namespace.

Comment: I will never call SQL in a loop , instead get SQL View/Table work for you and use Linq to filter.

Comment: Sorry what you mean @codebased

Comment: Do you mean I can use "Linq" instead of "SQL"?@codebased

Comment: You have to use sql to get data, but after that if you need some sort of filtering, selecting data based on a condition, you can use linq to do that, instead of looping thru the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're repeatedly executing the same query, you can add the parameters outside the loop and just fill them inside.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textInput", 0));

 for (int d = 0; d < YrStrList.Count; d++)
    {
 string text;
        text = YrStrList[d];
command.Parameters["@textInput"].Value = text ;
...
}
```